# Using CoRoutine Unity 3D Buttons

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm currently making a quiz game that has three buttons, from an object pool, and I want them to turn green or red depending on whether or not they are the correct answer.  This works perfectly.

When I add the coRoutine to change the button back to clear so the next question can be answered, the button almost never changes color after clicking and essentially nothing happens.  Would really appreciate any help!! Thank you.

```c#
public void HandelClick()
{
    var colors = GetComponent<Button> ().colors;

    if( ! answerData.isCorrect)
    {   
        colors.normalColor = Color.red;
        GetComponent<Button>().colors = colors;
    }
    else
    {
        colors.normalColor = Color.green;
        GetComponent<Button> ().colors = colors;

        playerMovement.dodge();
    }

    StartCoroutine("Revert");
    //gameController.AnswerButtonClicked(answerData.isCorrect);
}

IEnumerator Revert() 
{
    Debug.Log(" we are reverting " + Time.time);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.8f);
    Debug.Log(" we are reverting again " + Time.time);

    var colors = GetComponent<Button> ().colors;
    colors.normalColor = Color.clear;
    GetComponent<Button> ().colors = colors;
    gameController.AnswerButtonClicked(answerData.isCorrect);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the colors works as you said (you can see that in the Inspector of the `Button`)

The problem is that the `Image` component's color doesn't get updated automatically since the `Button` isn't receiving any pointer event like `PointerDown`, `PointerExit` etc => the new color is not applied to the `Image` (only in the cases where you do a new pointer event like enter, exit, up or down).

---

You could solve this by doing

```c#
GetComponent<Image>().color = colors.normalColor;
```

additional everywhere you change it.

---

Note: In general you should use `GetComponent` only once in `Awake`

```c#
private Button _button;
private Image _image;

private void Awake()
{
    _button = GetComponent<Button>();
    _image = GetComponent<Image>();
}
```

and than reuse the references `_image` and `_button`

Comment: Thank you!!!! This is exactly what I needed to do.  You da bomb.  I used the first solution but I might take a stab at the latter idea.

Comment: The second is more a hint regarding efficiency ;) You get the references over and over again ... reusing them would save resources ;)